# Android: How do I assign each of my ListView list items an individual icon?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm very new to Android delelopment, searching and reading various tutorials and using different parts of code from around the internet, trying to make sense of it as I go. Forgive me if my explanation isn't too great.

Currently I have a list created with 4 list items, what I'd like to do is assign a different icon to each of these list items, however, I've no idea how to do it, nor do I know what to search for.

Here's the code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainListView">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
 </TextView>
```

FirstList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FirstList extends Activity {

private ListView mainListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> myListAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView);

    String[] myList = new String[] {"List 1", "List 2", "List 3", "List 4"};

    ArrayList<String> listObjects = new ArrayList<String>();
    listObjects.addAll( Arrays.asList(myList));

    myListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, listObjects);

    mainListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any input you have, including any resources that you may recommend or critique of my code, as a newbie I'd rather not pick up bad habits from the start!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).  The SimpleAdapter allows you to map static data to complex views.  You should be able to find a number of examples with a quick search, for example [a tutorial](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/).

Comment: That gave me exactly what I needed to go on from a search perspective and I think I may of cracked it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add an ImageView to the row.xml file (the images will be rendered in the ImageView) - this shouldn't be too hard.

You will also have to create a custom ArrayAdapter (extending the ArrayAdapter class) and override the getView method - quite a common task, so you should easily find some examples on how this should be done. You can also have a look at the original ArrayAdapter class ([ArrayAdapter](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java&q=ArrayAdapter&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)) to see how the getView is implemented. At last you should add the image loading code in the getView method.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate please? My searches are coming up with the same recycled internet pages for various sites.